# Custom grub skips grub menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu/WIndows. I want to lock myself out of Windows on the weekdays. I put together this custom grub to skip grub menu on weekdays and saved in /boot/grub/custom.cfg. It works fine on weekdays, but it's now Saturday and it's still going straight into Ubuntu.

```
# This module creates special variables that return the current date/time
insmod datehook

# Boot "Ubuntu" on weekdays 
set default="Ubuntu"
if [ $DAY != SUNDAY -a $DAY != SATURDAY ]; then
    set GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
    set timeout=0
    set GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
fi
```

Comment: I have no experience with this whatsoever, but in the source code there are names `YEAR`,`MONTH`, `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND`, `WEEKDAY`. Totally without analyzing further, I would expect `DAY` to be the day of month. Are you sure you shouldn't use `WEEKDAY`? I'm not sure if names can be localized; possibly the case matters. If I were you I would just run `insmod datehook`, `echo $DAY` and `echo $WEEKDAY` in the GRUB console (hit `c` in GRUB menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kamil Maciorowski in the comments is correct.

If you look at the code of the datehook module ([link](https://github.com/rhboot/grub2/blob/master/grub-core/hook/datehook.c)), you can see that the `DAY` variable actually is the day of the month. What you need here is `WEEKDAY`. Also I'm not sure, but weekday names might be just "Sunday", "Saturday", without full capitalization, because [here](https://github.com/rhboot/grub2/blob/e7b8856f8be3292afdb38d2e8c70ad8d62a61e10/grub-core/lib/datetime.c) you can see how `grub_weekday_names` is initialized.